# How to count the number of customers conditionally per business?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

// transactions

| id | user_id | business_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 3000 |
| 2 | 11 | 1 | 2500 |
| 3 | 10 | 2 | 4000 |
| 4 | 10 | 2 | 2000 |
| 5 | 11 | 3 | 3000 |
| 6 | 10 | 1 | 5000 |
| 7 | 10 | 3 | 3000 |
| 8 | 11 | 2 | 1000 |

I want to count **the number of customers that have had their first transaction from somewhere else** per business.

**Note 1:** A user must have at least one transaction from a business to be known as a customer).

**Note 2:** Being "first transaction" would be detected based on a smaller id.

So here is the **expected result:**

```
+-------------+-------+
| business_id |  num  |
+-------------+-------+
| 1           | 0     | -- all its customers have had their first transaction this business
| 2           | 2     | -- for users #10 and #11 (since these two users have had their first transaction somewhere else)
| 3           | 2     | -- for user #10 and #11
+-------------+-------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

---

I really have no idea how to start writing this query. All I could do is counting the number of customers per business:

```
select business_id, count(1) num
from (select user_id, business_id from pos_transactions
      group by user_id, business_id) x
```

Comment: @Akina The first user's transaction is this: `select min(id) first_transaction_id, user_id from pos_transactions group by user_id`

Comment: @Akina Window functions are supported .. but I really like to know an approach without window functions ..

Comment: @Akina You are right, it must be counted like this `| 3 | 2 | -- for user #10 and #11` .. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT user_id, business_id, MIN(id) id
          FROM transactions
          GROUP BY user_id, business_id ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT user_id, MIN(id) id
          FROM transactions
          GROUP BY user_id )
SELECT cte1.business_id, SUM(cte1.id > cte2.id) num 
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 USING (user_id)
GROUP BY business_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc9315adae0320bf673db9f0bacfdb90

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value()` and aggregation:

```
select business_id,
       count(distinct customer_id) as num_customers,
       count(distinct case when first_business_id <> business_id then customer_id end) as num_customers_from_elsewhere
from (select t.*,
             first_value(business_id) over (partition by customer_id order by user_id) as first_business_id
      from transactions t
     ) t
group by business_id
```